# How to replace a string by another string by ignoring white space(s) in string without actually removing the white space(s) in java?

Tags: java, string

Consider an example,

```
String str1 = "hello world";
String str2 = str1.replace("low","xxx");
System.out.println(str2);
```

Now when I print str2, it should print helxxxorld.
My requirement is that I don't want to first remove all spaces in str1 and then replace. How can I do this?

Comment: Your expected output is "helxx xorld"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method, which allows you to pass a regex:

```
String str1 = "hello world";
String str2 = str1.replaceAll("l\\s*o\\s*w","xxx");
System.out.println(str2);
```

`\\s*` will match zero or more spaces after the `l` and `o` signs

Comment: Who says the input can be `hel oword`? I suppose it can be `hello       world`, with many spaces between the words

Comment: How says it cant? The question is "How to replace a string by another string by ignoring white space(s) in string without actually removing the white space(s)". That's not limited to a specifict input.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression with whitespace:

```
String str2 = str1.replaceAll("l\\s*o\\s*w", "xxx");
```

Output:

```
helxxxorld
```